# SIM5218E HTTP and TCP code

Tags: android, tcp, gps, 3g

I'm using the Cooking Hacks 5218E and have successfully used the Arduino MS-GPS assisted code to return a GPS Latitude and Longitude. I need to send this information via TCP to our server as a string.

I've been trying to just use the TCP send code from their website and have adjusted the APN etc and have this code:
[TCP_send_code](https://github.com/ValentmSTEM/gps_v1/blob/master/Arduino/Cooking-Hacks/TCP%20send)

I read that the buffer in HardwareSerial.h needs adjusting to 400 and have done that.
All the AT commands return okay until it gets to opening the network

```
     sprintf(aux_str, "AT+NETOPEN=\"TCP\",%s", TCP_port_1);
  answer = sendATcommand(aux_str, "Network opened", 20000);

  if (answer == 1)
  {
    Serial.println("Network opened");
    sprintf(aux_str, "AT+TCPCONNECT=\"%s\",%s", TCP_server_1, TCP_port_1);
    answer = sendATcommand(aux_str, "Connect ok", 20000);
    if (answer == 1)
    {
      Serial.println("Socket opened");
      sprintf(aux_str, "AT+TCPWRITE=%d", strlen(TCP_message_1));
      answer = sendATcommand(aux_str, ">", 20000);
      if (answer == 1)
      {
        sendATcommand(TCP_message_1, "Send OK", 20000);                
      }
      sendATcommand("AT+NETCLOSE", "OK", 20000);
    }
    else
    {
      Serial.println("Error opening the socket");    
    }
  }
  else
  {
    Serial.println("Error opening the network");    
  }
```

The serial monitor shows the error[Network Closed Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LCVkJ.jpg)

Any suggestions as to what might be the issue?

Thanks!

Comment: What has this to do with Android? I think you could much better introduce your setup. What are you doing? Whats this about? What is a 5218?